# How To Remove Images From Database using Image Path?

Tags: magento-1.9, delete

I need to remove images from **database** by using image path,

Paths:  m/1/m1.jpg, n/2/n2.jpg

```
Eg: www.abc.com/media/catalog/product/m/1/m1.jpg
```

my images located at media/catalog/product/5/2/53765.jpg, how can i remove, and large no.of images are located various location i know every image path location, how can i bulk remove?

Comment: Can you provide more information question to vague

Comment: @DavaGordon my images located at media/catalog/product/5/2/53765.jpg, how can i remove, and large no.of images are located various location i know every image path location, how can i bulk remove?